# Read and process large text file after every 2000 characters with a new line to it

Tags: c#, .net, large-files

I have a large text file which should be processed after every **2000** characters with a new line to it I have done so far as

```
string FilePath = Path.Combine(strFullProcessedPath, strFileName);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FilePath);
string firstLine = reader.ReadLine();
if (firstLine.Length > 2000)
{
    string text = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
    text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(.{2000})", "$1\r\n", RegexOptions.Multiline);
    reader.Close();
    File.WriteAllText(FilePath, text);
}
```

it is giving

> out of memory exception

please, anyone, refer me some advice

Comment: How big is the file in total? Are you running in a 32 or 64bit process? How much memory does the host system have available? As you are reading the whole file into memory, and then doing a regex based replace on it you'll have two copies in memory (at least)...

Comment: Your code doesnt do what youve said you needed. Your code only reads one line.   Do you want to just read 2000 characters and insert a linebreak or only if the line is >2000? what specifically are you trying to achieve

Comment: What is the size of the file?

Answer (score 1):

In case of *very large* (multi Gigabyte) file which *doesn't fit* memory, you can try storing processed data into a *temporary file*. Avoid `ReadAllText`, but read and write with a help of `buffer` (which is convenient to be of `2000` chars in the context)

```
  // Initial and target file
  string FilePath = Path.Combine(strFullProcessedPath, strFileName); 
  // Temporary file 
  string tempFile = Path.ChangeExtension(FilePath, ".~temp");        

  char[] buffer = new char[2000];

  using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FilePath)) {
    bool first = true;

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tempFile)) {
      while (true) {
        int size = reader.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        if (size > 0) {  // Do we have anything to write?
          if (!first) // Are we in the middle and have to add a new line?
            writer.WriteLine();

          for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            writer.Write(buffer[i]);
        }

        // The last (incomplete) chunk
        if (size < buffer.Length)
          break;

        first = false;
      }
    }
  }

  File.Delete(FilePath);
  // Move temporary file into target one
  File.Move(tempFile, FilePath);
  // And finally removing temporary file 
  File.Delete(tempFile);
```

**Edit:** Even if you have *not that large* (300MB, see comments) avoid *string processing* (several copies of the initial string can well lead to Out Of Memory).

Something like this

```
private static IEnumerable<string> ToChunks(string text, int size) {
  int n = text.Length / size + (text.Length % size == 0 ? 0 : 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    if (i == n - 1)
      yield return text.Substring(i * size);       // Last chunk
    else
      yield return text.Substring(i * size, size); // Inner chunk  
}

...

string FilePath = Path.Combine(strFullProcessedPath, strFileName);

// Read once, do not Replace ao do something with the string
string text = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);

// ... but extracting 2000 char chunks
File.WriteAllLines(FilePath, ToChunks(text, 2000));
```

Comment: The size of the file is 278MB which is having data in only single big line I'm running this in 64-bit processor

Comment: still, it is not working itis showing as the argument exception( my file path is E:\49057.u.2.3) please original file as destination file too

Comment: @Harish Dommati: I see, I'm very sorry for the errors; I've edited and checked both solutions

Comment: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count are greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection. I'm getting this error please review it

Comment: @Harish Dommati: `int size = reader.ReadBlock(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);`, please, notice my edit: `, 0,`

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply insert newlines into an exiting file - you need to rewrite the entire thing, basically. The easiest way to do that is to use two files - a source and destination - and then perhaps delete and rename at the end (so the temporary destination file takes the name of the original). This means you can now loop over the source file **without** reading it all into memory first; essentially, as pseudo-code:

```
using(...open source for read...)
using(...create dest for write...)
{
    char[] buffer = new char[2000];
    int charCount;
    while(TryBuffer(source, buffer, out charCount)) {
        // if true, we filled the buffer; don't need to worry
        // about charCount
        Write(destination, buffer, buffer.Length);
        Write(destination, CRLF);
    }
    if(charCount != 0) // final chunk when returned false
    {
        // write any remaining charCount chars as a final chunk
        Write(destination, buffer, charCount);
    }
}
```

So that leaves the implementation of `TryBuffer` and `Write`. In this case, `TextReader` and `TextWriter` are probably your friends, since you are dealing in characters rather than bytes.